# Passing the value of UILabel from FirstView to SecondView on a Tabbar Application

Tags: ios, uilabel, uitabbar, tabbarcontroller

I am trying to make an app which is getting data from a Weather Station. It is a tabbar based application.
I have two viewcontrollers: FirstViewController and SecondViewController.

In the FirstViewController I am doing most of the job.  Using the values which are coming from xml parsing and assigning these values to UILabels. That is working fine.
I am using if()  in order to assign UILabel the name of the wind according to its angle like:

**In my FirstViewController.m**

```
-(void)setWindDirectionName 
{    
   if(windDirectionAngle >= 0 && windDirectionAngle <=11.25f) labelWindDirectionName.text = @"N";
   if(windDirectionAngle > 11.25f && windDirectionAngle <=33.75f) labelWindDirectionName.text = @"NNE";
   if(windDirectionAngle > 33.75f && windDirectionAngle <= 56.25f) labelWindDirectionName.text = @"NE";
   if(windDirectionAngle > 56.25f && windDirectionAngle <=78.75f) labelWindDirectionName.text = @"ENE";
   if(windDirectionAngle > 78.75f && windDirectionAngle <=101.25f) labelWindDirectionName.text = @"E";
   .
   .
   . so on
```

**In the SecondViewController** I have UILabel and want it to take the value of **labelWindDirectionName.text** from **FirstViewController**.

**my SecondViewController.h**

```
 @interface SecondViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
 {
    NSString *windName;
  }
  @property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *windName;
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelCompassViewWindDirectionName;

  @end
```

**and in SecondViewController.m**

```
 FirstViewController *fvc = [[FirstViewController alloc]init]; 
 windName = fvc.labelWindDirectionName.text;
 labelCompassViewWindDirectionName.text = windName;//getting null probably making completely new  object;
```

How is it possible to pass data (UILABEL.TEXT) to another view in a tabbar based application? Where am I making mistake?
thanks

Comment: FirstViewController *fvc = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];  every time initializing  ... so it will  making completely new  object..... getting first view navigation controller object  then assign .....ok :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in your code

```
FirstViewController *fvc = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];
```

you are allocating new instance of FirstViewController so it will return null. If you need to access those names then you can store then in `NSUserDefaults` and then can access wherever you need.

Ex : In FirstViewController :
Save name and others as :

```
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:labelWindDirectionName.text forKey:@"windName"];//Note : Here windName is a key so you can save diffrent data using diffrent keys and same way can access those data using these keys whereever you require.
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

and for accessing in `SecondViewController` use this

```
labelCompassViewWindDirectionName.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"windName"];
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Get your `viewController` object Correclty and place that

```
 FirstViewController *fvc = (FirstViewController *)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:([self.navigationController.viewControllers count] -1)];
fvc.labelWindDirectionName.text = @"Something";
```

**If you are pushing one View Controller in the same tab then go for that approach.**
Since you said the previousController.. So, try this it will help

**For TabBar if you want then**

```
for(id object in [(UINavigationController *)self.tabBarController.selectedViewController viewControllers])
{
   if([object isKindOfClass:[FirstViewController class]])
    {
          FirstViewController *obj = (FirstViewController * ) object;
          obj.labelWindDirectionName.text = @"Something";
          break;
     } 
}
```

Comment: Now you are assuming that selectedViewController is a NavigationController. If it's known it would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set NSString property of SecondViewController to desired value and then in viewDidLoad method of SecondViewController set label text using value from this property.